# unexplained warning when using std::apply on empty tuple with msvc

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++17, compiler-warnings, stdapply

I have a warning about unreferenced variable when using std::apply on an empty tuple.
This snippet, inspired from [std::apply cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/apply) shows the issue:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <tuple>
#include <utility>

template <typename... Ts>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, std::tuple<Ts...> const& theTuple) {
    std::apply(
        [&os](Ts const&... tupleArgs) {
            os << '[';
            std::size_t n{0};
            ((os << tupleArgs << (++n != sizeof...(Ts) ? ", " : "")), ...);
            os << ']';
        },
        theTuple);
    return os;
}

int main() {
    // serialization example
    std::tuple myTuple{25, "Hello", 9.31f, 'c'};
    std::cout << myTuple << '\n';
    std::cout << std::tuple<>() << '\n';
}
```

[Live](https://godbolt.org/z/bP9PT1jbb)
MSVC, with `/permissive-`, outputs the following warning with the very last line:

> (10): warning C4189: 'n': local variable is initialized but not referenced
> (22): note: see reference to function template instantiation 'std::ostream &operator (std::ostream &,const std::tuple &)' being compiled

gcc and clangs do not issue anything.

As I'm using also `Werror`/`/we` I'd like to get rid of this warning (without using pragma, if possible).

1. Why does msvc behaves like that?
2. How can I get rid of this warning (adding a `if constexpr (sizeof...(Ts)>0)` inside the lambda?)?

Comment: [(void) n;](https://godbolt.org/z/6r9vo8TeT)

Comment: Or `[[maybe_unused]]` - https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/attributes/maybe_unused

Comment: Oh, yes the warning silencing is much easier with "traditionnal solutions". I validate.
Remains the first part, why is msvc doing that?
Thanks to you both

Comment: Both `(void)n;` and `[[maybe_unused]] std::size_t n{0};` work.

Comment: Personally, I'd be explicit with a `if constexpr` like you mentioned.

Comment: 1. msvc behaves like that because it is trying to help you spot unused variables (and its not clever enough to see that its unused intentionally)

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai But why does the variable would be unused in the empty case? It should be incremented to 1 then compared to 0 or does the fold expression been wiped out as the pack to expand is empty?

Comment: the latter, as you can see here:https://godbolt.org/z/TosvMTMMh

Comment: [fold cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/fold), Explanation case 3? the fold expression is replaced by `void()`. Correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Proposing an answer from the comments.

From [fold expression cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/fold):

> Explanation
> ...
> When a unary fold is used with a pack expansion of length zero, only the following operators are allowed:
>
> 1. Logical AND (&&). The value for the empty pack is true
> 2. Logical OR (||). The value for the empty pack is false
> 3. **The comma operator (,). The value for the empty pack is void()**

emphasis mine.
Thus in `((os << tupleArgs << (++n != sizeof...(Ts) ? ", " : "")), ...);`, if the tuple is empty, the expression becomes `void();`, resulting to `n` not being used, thus msvc is right to issue a warning.

Then, this warning can be silenced by a mere `[[maybe_unused]] std::size_t n{0};`.

Arguably we could also write:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <tuple>
#include <utility>

template <typename... Ts>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, std::tuple<Ts...> const& theTuple) {
    std::apply(
        [&os](Ts const&... tupleArgs) {
            os << '[';
            if constexpr (sizeof...(Ts)) {
                std::size_t n{0};
                ((os << tupleArgs << (++n != sizeof...(Ts) ? ", " : "")), ...);
            }
            os << ']';
        },
        theTuple);
    return os;
}

int main() {
    // serialization example
    std::tuple myTuple{25, "Hello", 9.31f, 'c'};
    std::cout << myTuple << '\n';
    std::cout << std::tuple<>() << '\n';
}
```

[Live](https://godbolt.org/z/zrdYxMz1W)

The `if constexpr` is more verbose but also more explicit with respect to when `n` is actually unused.
Strangely enough, I couldn't find a way to make gcc and clang issue a similar warning.